# Fullcalendar remove droping only on specific resource group or resource ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I want to make the fullcalendar event not drag and place with particular resource.

[image: event-fullcalendar]

For example the below code `Resource C and Resource G` I can drag and place the event. **I want to make event not draggable to the `Resource C and Resource G`.**

Comment for further information.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'resourceTimeline' ],
    header: {
      left: 'promptResource today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek'
    },
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    defaultView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
 editable: true,
    resources: [{"id":"a","title":"Auditorium A"},{"id":"b","title":"Auditorium B"},
 {"id":"c","title":"Auditorium C"},
 {"id":"d","title":"Auditorium D","children":[{"id":"d1","title":"Room D1"},
 {"id":"d2","title":"Room D2"}]},
 {"id":"e","title":"Auditorium E"},
 {"id":"f","title":"Auditorium F"},
 {"id":"g","title":"Auditorium G"},
 {"id":"h","title":"Auditorium H"},
 {"id":"i","title":"Auditorium I"}],
 events: [{"resourceId":"d","title":"event 1","start":"2019-08-04","end":"2019-08-06"},
 {"resourceId":"c","title":"event 3","start":"2019-08-05T12:00:00+00:00","end":"2019-08-06T06:00:00+00:00"},
 {"resourceId":"f","title":"event 4","start":"2019-08-05T07:30:00+00:00","end":"2019-08-05T09:30:00+00:00"},
 {"resourceId":"b","title":"event 5","start":"2019-08-05T10:00:00+00:00","end":"2019-08-05T15:00:00+00:00"},
 {"resourceId":"e","title":"event 2","start":"2019-08-05T09:00:00+00:00","end":"2019-08-05T14:00:00+00:00"}]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/timeline/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-timeline/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/interaction/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/timeline/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-common/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-timeline/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>


<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: I suggest you handle the [eventDrop](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDrop) callback. As you can see from that documentation, the info supplied will tell you which resource the event is being dropped on. So you can check if it's one you want to disallow. And then you run the "revert" callback which is also provided, which will send the event back to where it came from.

Comment: Okay. I will check.